# Pixi.JS: Using the Pixi Loader to create textures for inline SVG images

Tags: svg, textures, pixi.js

Everyone seems to recommend utilizing the Pixi Loader to load textures together, get updates on progress, etc. This works great so far.

However, I am wondering if there is a way to load a texture from an inline SVG using the Pixi Loader? Any insights would be appreciated.

(Note: I am looking to load the SVG as a texture, so I understand it will become a raster image, I am not looking for scalability features of SVG, but to simply reduce the amount of web requests needed by utilizing inline SVG images)

Comment: Pixi is webgl, svg isn't.

Comment: @RobertLongson Updated my question with more context; not looking to utilize native SVGs, thanks for your comment

Comment: Add a foreignObject to your svg, put a canvas element in that then write to the canvas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I was able to get this to work, was to make the URL passed into the loader be a base64 encoded dataURI. Everything after "base64," is just a base64 encoded svg. Example:

```
let svgTest = "data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB4bWxucz0iaHR0cDovL3d3dy53My5..."
Loader.shared.add('SvgTest',svgTest);
Loader.shared.load((loader, resources) => {
  //callback, do what you wish
});
```